# Unable to boot from Live USB on Dell Inspiron N7110

Tags: boot, usb, dell

I bought a Dell Inspiron N7110 and wanted to try Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit LiveUSB on it. I managed to boot from the USB, for a while (I saw the Ubuntu circle at the bottom of the screen), but then I only saw a blinking cursor on the black screen, that eventually froze completely. Then the laptop fan started to sound more and more and I was forced to shutdown.

I tried burning the same image of Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit to a CD and to boot from it. This worked as it should, with no problems, and I was able to explore the Live Session.

Does anyone knows what might be the cause of the problem that is preventing me from booting a Live USB from this laptop?

I have tried to boot from the same USB on my HP desktop computer and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Maybe it's a USB 3.0 port? did you try on any of the other USB jacks to see if some of them work better?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It never occured to me that it might be a USB 3.0 port, I will try the other ones as well and report back. Thanks again!

Comment: Using another USB port totally fixed the problem, thank you so much! I feel imbarassed that I didn't try that myself before posting a question here.

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years. Problem was solved by inserting USB flash drive into the correct USB slot instead of incompatible one. VTC as not reproducible. Furthermore it is Ubuntu 11.10 which hit EOL  ~2012.